# Git strange behaviour

Tags: git

I recently upgraded my ubuntu local server to 14.04. I don't know if it's related with upgrade or not, but things is there was no such problem before. The problem is,

[image]

Googled this problem, and found that, deleting this file will fix problem. Removed index.lock file. Got error:

```
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Tried to `git reset`. After reset, tried to add, commit and push. First try gone well. It pushed commit without any problem. But second try, again same problem.

Tried to remove repo and clone again. Same problem occurs.

Tried to `chown -R root:root /var/www`: no success

Also tried to chmod -R 777 .git/ of project. same thing

Any suggestions? What to do next?

Comment: When issuing your `git` commands, are you using `sudo` as well or not?

Comment: @Shah I'm acting as root allready

Comment: @Shah have you read my question at all?? this is first thing that I did.

Comment: @heron Try running `lsof` to see if something is holding files open under "/var/www". Also, usually that folder is open by the web-server process - so check to see if that's running.